# Can the Mirror of Life Trapping force multiple saves?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, saving-throw

The [Mirror of Life Trapping](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/mirror-of-life-trapping) can trap creatures in it.

> Any creature other than you that sees its reflection in the activated mirror while within 30 feet of it must succeed on a DC 15 Charisma saving throw or be trapped, along with anything it is wearing or carrying, in one of the mirror’s twelve extradimensional cells.

Does it force multiple saves? If someone stares at the mirror and remains there looking at themselves for 5 minutes, do they have to save more than once? Or only every time they blink?

What if they look away and look back on the mirror?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the information we need is in this sentence:

> "*Any creature other than you that sees its reflection in the activated mirror while within 30 feet of it must succeed on a DC 15 Charisma saving throw or be trapped...*"

If a save was to be made every round the description would say so, every other spell, ability or item that forces a save every round/minute/day/month etc. explicitly state as such. With no such descriptor present we must conclude that a repeat save is not required round after round.

**However!**

It also lacks the caveat of a successful saving throw preventing more saves from being required, such as with an Enchanter Wizard's *Instinctive Charm* which we must also assume is intentional.

What we can therefore conclude is that everytime a creature sees its own reflection it is forced to make the save, meaning if they look away and do something else and look into the mirror again the save must be made again. But if they continue to look at their own reflection uninterrupted for minutes on end then only the one save is required when they initially see themselves in the mirror.

Comment: This answer makes a nice compromise. I did something similar with my players, where each action they did related to the mirror would trigger a save (unless they told me they specifically didn't look at it or didn't break eye contact with their reflection)

Answer (score -1):

### Once, or once per activation

Adopting the “there are no hidden rules” rule, since there is no suggestion that multiple saving throws are required, they aren’t.

A creature “that sees its reflection in the activated mirror” makes “**a** DC 15 Charisma saving throw”. The previous paragraph spells out how the mirror is activated.

A person sees their reflection and from that point on they have seen it, even if they are still looking or are looking again or looked 30 years ago. Once you “see” Paris, you have forever after seen Paris even if you live there.

Whether the mirror “resets” when deactivated/reactivated is ambiguous so that’s a DM call.